# assign a value with spaces to a dynamically-named variable in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file which has the following text written into it -

```
hello h.i. b-y-e
```

I want to read this value into a variable. I have defined a function -

```
function read() { p=`cat $1`; echo "$p"; $2=`echo "$p"`; }
```

I get the following error -

```
hello h.i. b-y-e
-bash: v=hello: command not found
```

However, when I do -

```
p=`cat $filename`

text=`echo "$p"`
```

I have the desired string text. Can someone please explain the difference in behaviour as well as a way to acheive what I want to do.

Comment: `$2=\`echo "$p"\`` is not a valid statement. What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: I am trying to assign the value of $2 to $p

Comment: Can the input file have more than one line?

Comment: `read` is already a built-in command; pick another name for your function.

Comment: Yes, the input file can have more than one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> See what [WordSplitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) means in shell context

All you need to do to store it in a variable is,

```
fileContent="$(<input-file)"
printf "%s\n" "$fileContent"
hello h.i. b-y-e
```

(or) if you think it does not deserve 2 lines, just use a single-line as

```
printf "%s\n" "$(<input-file)"
```

(or) Using a function as

```
function getFileContents() {
   local input=$1
   printf "%s" "$(<input)"  
}

newVariable="$(getFileContents input-file)"
printf "%s\n" "$newVariable"
hello h.i. b-y-e
```

(and) if the requirement is bad enough to pass a variable to the function, something like

```
unset newVariable

function getFileContents() {
   local input=$1
   declare -n var=$2
   var="$(<$input)"
}

getFileContents file newVariable
printf "%s\n" "$newVariable"
hello h.i. b-y-e
```

Comment: I want to assign the contents of the file in the variable which was passed. That fails with your method as well.

Comment: @user2851669: You can reuse the logic,

Comment: This fails with `-bash: v=hello h.i. b-y-e: command not found`

Comment: I want to pass the variable as well in the function parameter itself.

Comment: like `getFileContents input-file newVariable`

Comment: @user2851669: This is a far better approach believe me, functions in bash do not have return string types, so what I have done is stored the function output in a new variable

Comment: You shouldn't even be using `eval` in *this* context.

Comment: Instead of `eval`: a nameref? `declare -n var=$2; var=$(< input)`, something like that?

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Appreciate it, ! and up-vote, it helps when people can provide constructive feedback like this.